# Create new MVC app using existing data and EF migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I need to port an existing ASP.NET MVC app into a new ASP.NET Core MVC app but I need to maintain the current domain model, EF migrations and data (ultimately I just need the new app to work with the existing database…if I need to start the migrations from start that’s no problem). I can’t find any explanations of how to do this, and from what I’ve read it appears porting from MVC to Core MVC isn’t without it’s traps and pitfalls.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework, or Entity Framework Core? And are the migrations part of the existing MVC app?

Comment: The existing MVC app uses EF obviously. I had intended to port to EF Core as part of the process, unless there is good reason not to?

Yes, the migrations are part of the existing MVC app.

Comment: Moving from EF6 to EF Core with migrations is not currently supported. The best option is to ensure that every copy of your database has the latest EF6 migration applied; port your code to EF Core without any migrations; create an initial EF Core migration, ensuring that the result matches your current database; and then comment out the content of the `Up` and `Down` methods for that migration.

Comment: With some wriggling, I managed to create a custom `SqlServerHistoryRepository` for one of my projects so that I could support both new and existing databases, so long as the existing ones had the last EF6 migration applied first. But it's not a clean solution.

Comment: [Existing migrations - Porting from EF6 to EF Core - Porting a Code-Based Model - EF | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-code#existing-migrations): *There isn't really a feasible way to port existing EF6 migrations to EF Core. If possible, it is best to assume that all previous migrations from EF6 have been applied to the database and then start migrating the schema from that point using EF Core.*